# Remove blue focus border around QGraphicsView

Tags: c++, qt, focus, maya, qgraphicsview

In Qt (for a Maya plugin), I have a QSplitter containing 2 QGraphicsViews.
One of these QGraphicsViews contains some QLineEdits.

Whenever I click on one of these QLineEdits, it gets a blue border (focus), but the QGraphicsView gets a blue border too. How to avoid the QGraphicsView to get a blue border ?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try setting style sheet eg:

```
QGraphicsView:focus {
border: none;
outline: none;
}
```